# Passing variable into xmlHTTPRequest as a URL parameter

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error

I use a combination of PHP and JS.

I have a URL parameter in my parent URL called market.

```
http://example.com?market=stackoverflow
```

I store it to a variable.

```
<?php 
    $market = $_GET['market'];
?
```

Then in JS:

```
<script>
    var market;
    market = <?php echo $market; ?>;
</script>
```

Then I have a function - xmlHTTPREQUEST. This is where the problem lies. I need to pass variable market into the function - append it to the script being called - mexx.php

```
<script>
    function test() {

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            xxx = (ajax.responseText);
            console.log(xxx);

          }
        };
        ajax.open("GET", "'mexx.php?market='+market", true);
        ajax.send(null);

    }
</script>
```

I can't see anything in console - all blank.

Where is the syntax error?

Comment: It should be `ajax.open("GET", "mexx.php?market="+ encodeURIComponent(market), true);`, but why do you need to send something that the server already has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra double quotes `"` in following line :

```
ajax.open("GET", "'mexx.php?market='+market", true);
_________________^_________________________^
```

Should be :

```
ajax.open("GET", 'mexx.php?market='+market, true);
```

Also put double qoutes `"` arround :

```
market = <?php echo $market; ?>;
```

Should be :

```
market = "<?php echo $market; ?>";
_________^______________________^
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct. Also, I just found out that I had to put quotes between the php echo. market = "<?php echo $market; ?>";  Your answer and the quotes for the echo solved my issue. Thank you.